# What does the -c option of sg do?

Tags: linux, bash

What does the -c option of sg do?  At least on my machine, the man page fails to explain this option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not documented in the man page, but looking at the source code it looks like it runs the command via "/bin/sh -c" instead of executing it directly.  I think it is there mostly for compatibility with the sg command on other Unix systems.

Answer (score 1):

> SYNOPSIS
>
> ```
>    sg [-] [group [-c ] command]
> ```
>
> DESCRIPTION
>
> ```
>     The sg command works similar to newgrp but accepts a command.
>     The command will be executed with the /bin/sh shell.
> ```

As you can see, sg accepts a command after the -c switch ( we can tell that by looking at the synopsis ) which will be executed using /bin/sh shell.